# Using a for loop to access inputs in snakemake for arguments that don't accept lists

Tags: python, snakemake

I want to use the [**`gatk MakeVcfSampleNameMap`**](https://javadoc.io/static/org.broadinstitute/gatk/4.1.4.0/picard/vcf/MakeVcfSampleNameMap.html) tool to generate a tab-delimited file that maps sample names to the corresponding VCF files in a Snakemake workflow. These vcfs are in a directory `input/`

***expected output - > (sample_name_map.txt)***

```
input/vcf1.vcf.gz   control5-a
input/vcf2.vcf.gz   control5-c
```

**`MakeVcfSampleNameMap`** accepts a single `--INPUT` argument at a time, so I have to submit multiple VCF files to it in the form:

- `--INPUT {input.vcfs[0]}`
- `--INPUT {input.vcfs[1]}`, etc.

***current snakemake rule***:

```
rule MakeVcfSampleNameMap:
    input:
        vcfs=["input/vcf1.vcf.gz", "input/vcf2.vcf.gz"],
    output:
        "sample_name_map.txt",
    shell:
        "gatk MakeVcfSampleNameMap \
        --INPUT {input.vcfs[0]} \
        --INPUT {input.vcfs[1]} \
        --OUTPUT {output}"
```

How can I use a loop in the Snakemake rule to access all the VCF files, as this is cumbersome for many input files?

Answer (score 3):

What about this, not tested but hopefully you get the idea:

```
rule MakeVcfSampleNameMap:
    input:
        vcfs=["input/vcf1.vcf.gz", "input/vcf2.vcf.gz"],
    output:
        "sample_name_map.txt",
    params:
        gatk_input=lambda wc, input: ' '.join(['--INPUT %s' % x for x in input.vcfs]),
    shell:
        r"""
        gatk MakeVcfSampleNameMap {params.gatk_input} \
            --OUTPUT {output}
        """
```

And if your input is a directory, something like:

```
import glob


rule MakeVcfSampleNameMap:
    input:
        dir="input",
    output:
        "sample_name_map.txt",
    params:
        gatk_input=lambda wc, input: " ".join(
            ["--INPUT %s" % x for x in glob.glob(str(input.dir) + "/*.vcf.gz")]
        ),
    shell:
        r"""
        gatk MakeVcfSampleNameMap {params.gatk_input} \
            --OUTPUT {output}
        """
```

Comment: Thanks, @dariober. This is how short I was looking to get it down to. Now to testing...

Comment: Not sure if this is cleaner, but I've used `gatk_input=lambda wc, input: ' --INPUT '.join(input.vcfs)` then the shell command has `gatk MakeVCFSampleNameMap --INPUT {params.gatk_input}`

Comment: Thanks @Troy, yes this is cleaner, though the shell command needs the flag output `gatk MakeVcfSampleNameMap --INPUT {params.gatk_input} --OUTPUT {output}`

Answer (score 0):

This python script (`make_vcf_sample_map.py`) does the trick, but I'm open to suggestions on how to improve it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

# Get the directory path from the command line arguments
directory = sys.argv[1]

# Get a list of all the VCF files in the directory
vcf_files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.vcf.gz')]

# Create a list of tuples with the file paths and names
file_list = []
for vcf_file in vcf_files:
    file_name = os.path.splitext(vcf_file)[0]
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, vcf_file)
    file_list.append((file_path, file_name))

# Sort the list by the second element of each tuple (the file name)
file_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

# Write the file names and paths to a TSV file
with open('sample_name_map.tsv', 'w') as tsv_file:
    for file_path, file_name in file_list:
        tsv_file.write(f'{file_path}\t{os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]}\n')
```

This script is then called from within a snakemake rule like this:

```
rule generate_sample_name_map:
    input:
        directory="input",
    output:
        "sample_name_map.txt",
    shell:
        "python make_vcf_sample_map.py {input.directory} > {output}"
```